# Python. Вывод цветного текста в файл .txt в кодировке utf-8

Tags: python, работа-с-текстом

Работаю над перезаписывающимся текстовым файлом. Возможно ли сделать, чтобы текст выводился цветным? Пробовал использовать termcolor и подобную конструкцию:

```
'{blue}"a"{endcolor}'.format(blue='\033[96m', endcolor='\033[0m')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Это невозможно.**

`\033[96m` и ему подобные -- команды для консоли и работать будут только в консоли.

---

Возможно, вам имеет смысл в файл писать в формате html, пример:

```
with open('1.html', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write('<font color="blue">Hello</font> <font color="red">World</font>!')
```